# How to apply search for dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-select2

I am using select2min.js for dropdown of select box.

Here it is working for single drop down

```html
<select>
<option>abc</option>
</select>
```

for this it is working fine by using

```
$("#myId0").select2({
            data: []
          });
```

above code.

If I have dropdown and it's containing add button then in the drop down the search box is not coming.

$scope.myList; is containg the all my dropdowns.can I get the same functionality by using the `$scope.myList`.

[This is the link for example](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

Comment: so you are saying that when you are adding another search box dynamically then for second-one search box not comming

Comment: exactly same, in my dynamic dropdown also data will be there bydefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to convert `id` to `class`

```
<select class="myId"></select>
```

2.And then change the code like this:-

```
$(document).find(".myId").select2({
  data: []
});
```

Comment: @user9130953  din't get you

Comment: I don't think so